# How to find a "least squares" line with a known slope?

Tags: least-squares

I have gps trackings that I **know** they fall into a certain pattern - a line with a **known angle**. How do I find the line that minimizes the distances of the points from it but is in the correct angle?

Unfortunately, I can't post an image for example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you would try to solve it, at least your thoughts about it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I well understand, you have a set of $n$ points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_k,y_k),..., (x_n,y_n)$ and you want to fit a straight line $y=ax+b$ which coefficient $a$ is known.

This is a regression problem of the kind  $Y(x)=b$ where $Y(x)=y(x)-ax$

Hense $$b\simeq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (y_k-ax_k)$$

In this particular case ($a$ known), the adjusted value of $b$ is the same if we consider the orthogonal distances.

Comment: Why $\simeq$ and not $=$ ? Cheers

Comment: OK for $=$ if you prefer. Cheers !

Comment: Hi JJacquelin, thank you for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how can I also get the estimated points on the line?

Comment: What do you mean exactly as "estimated points on the line" ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, is there a way, after I have the equation, to match a point on the line for every point from the input?

Comment: The coordinates of the point $(X_k , Y_k)$ located on the straight line and at the shortest distance from the point $(x_k , y_k)$ are : $$X_k=\frac{ay_k+x_k-ab}{a^2+1}$$ $$Y_k=\frac{a^2y_k+ax_k+b}{a^2+1}$$

Comment: Hi again, is the correct way to apply **weighted least square** is to multiply  wk*(yk−axk) ? where 0<wk<1 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider your data as points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you have $n$ data points, then you want to find $\beta_1 ,\beta_2$ such that $y\simeq\beta_1+\beta_2x$.
$$
       X\beta= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & x_1 \\
        1 & x_2 \\
        1 & x_3  \\
        \vdots & \vdots\\
        1 & x_n\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1\\
\beta_2\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}=y
$$
If you have received lots of data from gps your $X$ matrix is tall and a pseudoinverse can be found as:

$$
X^+=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
$$

And then you can find the solution:

$$
\beta=X^+y
$$

It's MATLAB code is

```
beta=X\y;
```

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) for more information.

---

If $\beta_2$ is known and you want to find $\beta_1$ such that, $y-\beta_2x\simeq\beta_1$ then

$$
X\beta= \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    1   \\
    \vdots\\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1-\beta_2x_1\\
y_2-\beta_2x_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n-\beta_2x_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
X^+=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T=(\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &
    1  &
    1   &
    \cdots&
    1 
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    1   \\
    \vdots\\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix})^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &
    1  &
    1   &
    \cdots&
    1 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
And the answer will be:

$$
\beta_1=X^+y=\frac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &
    1  &
    1   &
    \cdots&
    1 
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1-\beta_2x_1\\
y_2-\beta_2x_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n-\beta_2x_n
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$
\beta_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (y_i-\beta_2x_i)
$$

Comment: If I well understand the question of user3316066, the parameter $\beta_2$ is known and given as an initial input. So, the regression is of lower case (no need to optimise and compute another value for $\beta_2$).

Comment: Edited to work with both assumptions

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation. It's the best that I found after searching the net for about 15 minutes.